# Is Object.prototype an object and is prototype somehow not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I type `Object.prototype` into the Chrome console it displays `Object{}`

If I assign it to a variable `var proto = Object.prototype` it displays `Object{}`

But if I check for it's prototype

```
var proto = Object.prototype
proto.prototype;
```

If `proto` is an `Object{}` and `proto.prototype` is undefined does that means that`Object()` *is* an `Object()` that doesn't inherit from anything?

Also, would this be the same as `Object.prototype.prototype`?

Comment: It is an object, and it has no prototype as it is one.

Comment: So is prototype kind of like `Object.create(null)`?

Comment: When it comes to inheritance, JavaScript only has one construct: objects. Each object has an internal link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. null, by definition, has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.

Comment: Why does it return undefined and not null?

Comment: Because it's not defined, the prototype chain has ended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an *Object* has a prototype, the prototype is also an *Object*. These *Objects* all chain together until you reach *null*, which is the end of the *prototype chain*.

```
// Object is a constructor
Object.prototype; // Object {}, will be the prototype of `new Object`s
// Object.prototype is an Object
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype); // null, we are at the end of the chain
```

You should also note, however, that you can't keep accessing the `obj.prototype` property, as this is only applicable to *Constructors*, consider

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype; // Foo {}
// vs
(new Foo).prototype; // undefined
```

The correct way to find the prototype of an *Object* is by using `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`,

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(new Foo) === Foo.prototype; // true
```

---

It may also be of note that legacy browsers may not support `Object.getPrototypeOf`, in which case many offer the property `obj.__proto__`. However, try to avoid using `__proto__` outside of a shim for such browsers if you need to access the prototype chain.

---

Finally, using `new` with a *Constructor* isn't the only way to create this chain, you can set them up using `Object.create`

```
var a = Object.create(null),
    b = Object.create(a), // b will inherit from a
    c = Object.create(b); // c will inherit from b, hence also a
a.foo = 'foo';
b.bar = 'bar';

a instanceof Object; // false

a.bar; // undefined
c.foo + c.bar === 'foobar'; // true
```

Also consider

```
c.prototype; // undefined
// vs
Object.getPrototypeOf(c) === b; // true
```

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara please see the last code block. The end of the prototype chain will be `null`. Prototypes are different to properties.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I continued with the same variables from the block above, so `b = Object.create(a)`

Answer (score 3):

`Object.prototype` is the furthest you can go up the prototype chain.

It `Object.prototype` has no prototype property, so what you see is `undefined`. In actuality, it's prototype is `null`. Which you can confirm with either the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method or the `__proto__` property.

```
 Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype); // null
 Object.prototype.__proto__; // null
```

The `prototype` property isn't a reliable way to traverse the prototype chain, as in many cases, it won't exist.

```
function MyObj() {}
MyObj.prototype.a = 3;
(new MyObj).prototype; // undefined

Object.create({ a: 3 }).prototype; // undefined
```

The [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is not a standard and may be removed from a future edition of ES. But in compatible browsers, it will work in the expected way.

```
Object.create({ a: 3 }).__proto__; // Object {a: 3}
```

Comment: That is not true. The prototype of `Object.prototype` is indeed `null`, try typing `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)` in your console. You probably confused the `prototype` property (which is available on constructors) and the actual prototype (accessed via the non-standard `__proto__` property or the ES5 `Object.getPrototypeOf()` function). Indeed, `Object.prototype.prototype` results in `undefined`, as according to the above statement, only functions have the `prototype` property, and `Object` is a function/constructor, while `Object.prototype` itself is not.

Comment: `obj.prototype.prototype` will only exist if `obj.prototype` is another _constructor (i.e. function)_, the correct way to follow the prototype chain is `Object.getPrototypeOf`

Comment: Updating answer to reflect these comments.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The ECMAScript 5.1 specification (which is the normative document on which all JavaScript implementations are based) explicitly states this: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4

Comment: @rhino Thanks! My bad, I was looking at the ES6 draft, which makes no mention of it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara [It isn't so hard to find in the ES6 draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object), the section's header is even the same as in ES5.1.

Comment: @rhino So it is. I guess my mistake was looking for it under the `getPrototypeOf` section.

Answer (score 1):

A lot can be said about prototypes, but the brief explanations below could help clarify the subject to make it easier to understand:

**A) `prototype` is a property of functions**.

`Object.constructor` returns `function Function() { [native code] }`, so we can get its `prototype`, just like how you were able to get the `prototype` of `Object` itself. This is because it is a function. `typeof Object` returns `"function"`. On the other hand, `typeof Object.prototype` returns `"object"`, so you were unable to get the prototype of `Object.prototype`.

```
// get prototype property of a function
var hello = function () {};
hello.prototype // hello {}

// get prototype property of an object
typeof hello.prototype // "object"
hello.prototype.prototype // undefined
hello = {};
hello.prototype // undefined
```

We can add properties and methods to a `Constructor` (which is a function) using the `prototype` property.

```
function Hello() {}
Hello.prototype.print = function () { console.log('hello'); };

// not using a constructor
var hello = Hello(); // undefined
hello.print(); // ERROR

// using a constructor
hello = new Hello(); // Hello {print: function}
hello.print(); // "hello"
```

**B) `__proto__` is a property of all objects (which includes functions)**.

Note that `Object.__proto__` is equivalent to `Object.constructor.prototype` and `Object.getPrototype(Object)`.

There is no `prototype` property of `Object.prototype` because it is not a function. But because it is an object, we can do `Object.prototype.__proto__` which returns `null`. Getting `null` means we are at the end of the prototype chain.

Even functions have `__proto__`:

```
function Hello() {}
Hello.__proto__ // function Empty() {}
```

`__proto__` is the internal prototype that is used by JS engines for inheritance/delegate chaining.

```
function Hello() {}
var hello = new Hello();

hello.__proto__ === Hello.prototype // true
```